# 2amigos DataRangePicker. Display over input.

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, yii2, yii-widgets, bootstrap-daterangepicker

**Problem**

I set orientation, but it's still at the bottom. What's the problem?

**Code**

```
<?=$form->field($contactUsModel, 'planningToTravelFrom')
                            ->widget(\dosamigos\datepicker\DateRangePicker::className(), [
                                'attributeTo'   => 'planningToTravelTo',
                                'form'          => $form, // best for correct client validation
                                'language'      => 'es',
                                'size'          => 'lg',
                                'clientOptions' => [
                                    'autoclose'   => true,
                                    'orientation' => 'top',
                                    'format'      => 'dd-M-yyyy'
                                ]
                            ]);?>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was in

1. Should be `'orientation' => 'bottom'`
2. Not works with [date-range-picker bugfix](https://github.com/uxsolutions/bootstrap-datepicker/issues/978)

```
$("#contactform-planningtotravelfrom, #contactform-planningtotravelto").datepicker().on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
        // prevent datepicker from firing bootstrap modal "show.bs.modal"
        event.stopPropagation();
    });
```